# Attribute error trying to remove stopwords from rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove stopwords from rows in a dataframe. Unfortunately, I am getting an error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'str'
> ```

due to

```
----> 8     for i in text.str.lower().split():
```

from the code

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def remove_stopwords(text):
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
fresh_text = []

for i in text.str.lower().split():
    if i not in stop_words:
        fresh_text.append(i)

return(' '.join(fresh_text))

df['text'] = df['Quotes'].apply(remove_stopwords)
```

I have found this question that should be able to fix this issue:

[How to solve the Attribute error 'float' object has no attribute 'split' in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736900/how-to-solve-the-attribute-error-float-object-has-no-attribute-split-in-pyth)

but I am probably making some mistakes in adding `str`. before lower and/or split.

Can you please have a look at it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should aim to not write for loops when using pandas anyway. This can be done in a list comprehension. But I am guessing the datatype of `df['Quotes']` is not string, but rather float. You can cast that column as a string before your apply call.

```
df['Quotes'] = df['Quotes'].astype(str)
```

The str method of a pandas series only applies to Objects (strings, as defined by Pandas). This won't work for a float type, hence the error. Also, you are unnecessarily generating stop words per each row. This is very inefficient (as apply is called per row). Generate the stop word corpus outside the function. Also, look towards vectorized string functions as that may be applicable here.

Comment: Thank you justahuman. It worked. (I need to wait for other 5 minutes, than I will mark your answer). Thanks!

Comment: Great! I added a few comments if speed is of importance in your analysis (Vectorization, apply function scope).